# HCL Domino Monitoring Configuration (events4): is it possible to generate and use application events?

Tags: ibm-domino

I checked the (Help) databases but couldn't find out if I can create Custom Application Events, and if I can, how they can be used. For instance, I'd like an Agent to write a specific text in the log.nsf database and DDM should pick it up and process it according to what's specified in the Handler. Or if there is an XPages error, I can output something to the log database and DDM should find out about it and process it.

How can this be accomplished? Is there a description somewhere available? TIA

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer in Slack (sorry):

```
Dim session As New NotesSession
Dim agentLog As NotesLog
Set agentLog = session.CreateLog("Trigger DDM Event")
Call agentLog.LogEvent("Error caused by agent '" _
& session.CurrentAgent.Name & "'.", _
"EventDispatcher", EV_SERVER, SEV_WARNING1)
```

This seems to be the way to generate system events in Domino programmatically.